# iOS device disconnects instantly after connecting

Tags: ios

I made an app which receives messages from my raspberry pi via a MQTT-server, but when I start the app, the app immediately disconnects and is not able to receive any message.

```
import Moscapsule

var input: String = ""

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// set MQTT Client Configuration
let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iOS Device", host: "192.168.178.27", port: 1883, keepAlive: 10000)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mqttConfig.onConnectCallback = { returnCode in
        NSLog("Return Code is \(returnCode.description)")
    }

    mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
        NSLog("MQTT Message received: payload=\(String(describing: mqttMessage.payloadString))")
        input = mqttMessage.payloadString!;
        print(input);

    }
    // create new MQTT Connection
    let mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig)

    // publish and subscribe
    mqttClient.publish(string: "message", topic: "RPI3B/iOS", qos: 2, retain: false)
    mqttClient.subscribe("RPI3B/iOS", qos: 2)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

This my code

```
1513018389: New client connected from 192.168.178.13 as iOS Device (c1, k10000).
1513018389: Sending CONNACK to iOS Device (0, 0)
1513018389: Received PUBLISH from iOS Device (d0, q2, r0, m1, 'RPI3B/iOS', ... (7 bytes))
1513018389: Sending PUBREC to iOS Device (Mid: 1)
1513018389: Received SUBSCRIBE from iOS Device
1513018389:     RPI3B/iOS (QoS 2)
1513018389: iOS Device 2 RPI3B/iOS
1513018389: Sending SUBACK to iOS Device
1513018389: Received DISCONNECT from iOS Device
1513018389: Client iOS Device disconnected.
```

This is what my MQTT server shows on my raspberry PI

```
2017-12-11 19:53:09.863392+0100 MSQTTtest[9620:739633] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS Device sending CONNECT
2017-12-11 19:53:09.864524+0100 MSQTTtest[9620:739636] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS Device sending PUBLISH (d0, q2, r0, m1, 'RPI3B/iOS', ... (7 bytes))
2017-12-11 19:53:09.864924+0100 MSQTTtest[9620:739633] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS Device sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 2, Topic: RPI3B/iOS, QoS: 2)
2017-12-11 19:53:09.865260+0100 MSQTTtest[9620:739633] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS Device sending DISCONNECT
```

This is what my console shows on Xcode

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of what you're using but I wonder if you have a scope problem with `mqttClient`.  What if you make it an instance variable instead of local?

Comment: Changing the mqttClient to var didn't work

Comment: But did you move it out of the function so that it had instance scope?

Comment: That worked, but know I get this message in console: MSQTTtest[13095:889733] [MOSQUITTO] DEBUG   Client iOS Device received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'RPI3B/iOS', ... (4 bytes)), but the message is not printed.